# multiplying list of items by a certain number 'x'

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, multiplication, cdr

How would you write a procedure that multiplies each element of the list with a given number (x).If I give a list '(1 2 3) and x=3, the procedure should return (3 6 9)

My try:

```
(define (mul-list list x)
(if (null? list)
1
(list(* x (car list))(mul-list (cdr list)))))
```

The above code doesnt seem to work.What changes do I have to make ? Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the text book example where you should use [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), instead of reinventing the wheel:

```
(define (mul-list lst x)
  (map (lambda (n) (* x n)) lst))
```

But I guess that you want to implement it from scratch. Your code has the following problems:

- You should not call `list` a parameter, that clashes with the built-in procedure of the same name - one that you're currently trying to use!
- The base case should return an empty list, given that we're building a list as output
- We build lists by `cons`ing elements, not by calling `list`
- You forgot to pass the second parameter to the recursive call of `mul-list`

This should fix all the bugs:

```
(define (mul-list lst x)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (* x (car lst))
            (mul-list (cdr lst) x))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(mul-list '(1 2 3) 3)
=> '(3 6 9)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please suggest me a beginners book for learning Scheme :)

Comment: @mike sure, with pleasure :) . "The Little Schemer" and "How to Design Programs" are fantastic, and "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" is one of the best programming books ever written, although it's a tad more advanced

Comment: Thank you so much :)  Óscar López . That was a nice list

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I *was* going to expand your answer by talking about tail recursion and offer an alternative way to write the `map` procedure... But the more I learn about racket's stack, the less this seems important. Do you think it would be beneficial for me to introduce this topic and demonstrate some workarounds? I ask you specifically because I don't want to waste the time of other experts (like you) by potentially muddying the water with things I may not understand as well as you.

Comment: @naomik It'd be ok to show a tail recursive version, but bear in mind that OP is still learning and it might be an advanced topic for him ;) Besides, `map` is usually implemented in a non-tail-recursive fashion.

Answer (score 0):

For and its extensions (for*, for/list, for/first, for/last, for/sum, for/product, for/and, for/or etc: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) are very useful for loops in Racket:

```
(define (ml2 lst x)
  (for/list ((item lst))
    (* item x)))
```

Testing:

```
(ml2 '(1 2 3) 3)
```

Output:

```
'(3 6 9)
```

I find that in many cases, 'for' implementation provides short, simple and easily understandable code.